# Showing that generating function satisfies function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Suppose that the sequence $S = (s_0, s_1, \dots )$ is defined by:

$s_0 = 0$, $s_1= 1$ and $s_{n+2} = s_{n+1}+2s_n$ for $n \ge 0$. Thus, $S = (0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 11, 21,...)$.

Show that the generating function $S(x) = s_0 + s_1 x + s_2 x^2 + \dots$ satisfies
$S(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x - 2x^2}$.

I would start this problem with $(1,1,1,1,1,1,...) = 1/(1-x)$ and manipulate it until I end up with $S(x) = x/(1-x-2x^2)$, but I don't know how to manipulate it.

Comment: You can get formulas much more readable and much easier by using TeX instead of HTML. I've done a few as example (and removed a nested <sub> in passing that I think was not intended).

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a basic MathJax tutorial, with links to more information.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this; here’s the one that I prefer. Start with your recurrence:

$$s_n=s_{n-1}+2s_{n-2}\;.\tag{1}$$

This holds for $n\ge 2$, and in addition you have the initial conditions $s_0=0$ and $s_1=1$. If we assume that $s_n=0$ for all negative integers $n$, $(1)$ also works for $n=0$; it fails only for $n=1$, when it gives $s_1=0$ instead of $s_1=1$. I’ll fix this by adding a term:

$$s_n=s_{n-1}+2s_{n-2}+[n=1]\;,\tag{2}$$

where $[n=1]$ is an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) whose value is $1$ if $n=1$ and $0$ otherwise. The modified recurrence $(2)$ gives the correct value for all $s_n$, again on the assumption that $s_n=0$ for $n<0$.

Now multiply $(2)$ by $x^n$ and sum over $n\ge 0$:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(s_{n-1}+2s_{n-2}+[n=1]\right)x^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}s_{n-1}x^n+2\sum_{n\ge 0}s_{n-2}x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}[n=1]x^n\\\\
&=x\sum_{n\ge 0}s_{n-1}x^{n-1}+2x^2\sum_{n\ge 0}s_{n-2}x^{n-2}+x\\\\
&=x\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n+2x^2\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n+x\;.
\end{align*}\tag{3}$$

Now let $g(x)$ be the generating function: by definition

$$g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n\;.$$

From $(3)$ we see that $g(x)=xg(x)+2x^2g(x)+x$, and solving this for $x$ yields

$$g(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-2x^2}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

What does $S(x)=\frac x{1-x-2x^2}$ really mean? It means that if you multiply the foormal power series $S(x)$ by the polynomial $1-x-2x$ then you should get the polynomial $x$ (which is a power series whose coefficients become $0$ after the one for $x$). So just do the multiplication!

From the initial terms of $S$ you get that the product starts with $0x^0+1x^1$ as it should (and you only needed the constant term $1$ of $1-x-2x^2$ to find this). It remains to show that the remaining coefficients in the product are all $0$. But the coefficient of $x^{n+2}$ in the product is $s_{n+2}-s_{n+1}-2s_n$ for all $n\in\mathbf N$, and by the recurrence relation this is always $0$.

So you see the generating function identity just reflects the initial conditions and the recurrence relation in a very straightforward way (or maybe it would be more appropriate to say "straightbackward"). The correspondence is so directd that you should not have difficulty *guessing* the proper identity, given any similarly defined recursive sequence.