# Summation of Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Let $f_n$ be the sequence of Fibonacci numbers.
We need to show that

$$\sum_{n\ge0} f_n x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x-x^2}$$

I remember a solution when we are using the generating functions like:

$f(x) = F_0 + F_1x + F_2 x^2 + F_3x^3$
Then multiply by $x$ and $x^2$ both sides and get $(1-x-x^2)f(x) = F_0 + (F_1-F_0)x=x$ and the result follows.

However I don't quite understand how this works. Also I would like to come up to similar expressions for $\sum_{n\ge0} f_{2n} x^n$  and  $\sum_{n\ge0} f_{2n+1} x^n$.

Comment: There are a [decent number of places](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=fibonacci+generating+function&spell=1&sa=X&ei=b2k1UdaNHciu2AWos4CADA&ved=0CCwQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.b2I&fp=6a9f4e80b80a2090&biw=1276&bih=684) where this is explained in detail.  Rather than "I don't understand how this works," it would be better if you could ask a concrete question.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/291167/12042) to a similar question should at least give you some ideas.

Comment: BTW the numerator of the generating function should be $x$ instead of $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a not-so-rigorous look at the question.

The Fibonacci Numbers are defined by the relationship

$$f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_{n}$$

Multiplying by $x^{n+2}$ on both sides, we obtain

$$f_{n+2}x^{n+2}=x\times f_{n+1}x^{n+1}+x^2\times f_{n}x^{n}$$

Summing  as $n$ ranges from zero to infinity, we have

$$\sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n+2}x^{n+2}=x\times \sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n+1}x^{n+1}+x^2\times \sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n}x^{n}$$

We can rewrite this as

$$\left(\sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n}x^{n}-f_{1}x-f_{0}\right)=x\times \left(\sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n}x^{n}-f_{0}\right)+x^2\times \sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n}x^{n}$$

Re-arranging the equation, we have

$$\sum ^\infty _{n=0} f_{n}x^{n}(1-x-x^2)=x(f_0+f_1)+f_0$$

From which the result follows.

Comment: btw , why after "We can rewrite this as" the index of the summation remains the same?

Comment: it's because the sum is from zero to infinity, so the sum is still to infinity. if on the left-hand side the sum was from 0 to 10, for example, then the limits would have to change to from 0 to 12.

Comment: that is, if we're looking at the sum $$\sum ^{10} _{n=0} f_{n+2}x^{n+2}$$, then when we change the index, we would get $$\left(\sum ^{12} _{n=0} f_{n}x^{n}\right)-f_1x-f_0$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
g(x) & = \dfrac1{1-x-x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x+x^2)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k(1+x)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k \sum_{l=0}^k \dbinom{k}l x^l\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^k \dbinom{k}l x^{k+l} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m \left(\sum_{l=0}^m \dbinom{m-l}l\right) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} g_{m+1} x^m
\end{align}
Now use the fact that
$$\dbinom{n}r + \dbinom{n}{r+1} = \dbinom{n+1}{r+1}$$ to conclude that
$$g_{m+1} = g_m + g_{m-1}$$
with $g_1 = 1$, $g_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{r|cccccccc}\color{Red}{1}f(x) &  \color{Red}{F_0} & + & \color{Red}{F_1}x & + & \color{Red}{F_2}x^2 & + & \color{Red}{F_3}x^3 &  \cdots \\
\hline \color{Green}{x}f(x) & & &  \color{Green}{F_0}x & + & \color{Green}{F_1}x^2 & + & \color{Green}{F_2}x^3 &  \cdots \\
\hline \color{Blue}{x^2}f(x) & & & & & \color{Blue}{F_0}x^2 & + & \color{Blue}{F_1}x^3 &  \cdots \\ 
\hline (\color{Red}{1}-\color{Green}{x}-\color{Blue}{x^2})f(x) & \color{Red}{F_0} & + & (\color{Red}{F_1}-\color{Green}{F_0})x & + & (\color{Red}{F_2}-\color{Green}{F_1}-\color{Blue}{F_0})x^2 & + & (\color{Red}{F_3}-\color{Green}{F_2}-\color{Blue}{F_1})x^3  & \cdots \\\end{array}$$

This is $F_0+(F_1-F_0)x+0+0+\cdots=x$, since $F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}-F_n=0$ for all $n\ge0$. Once you reach the functional equation $(1-x-x^2)F(x)=x$, you divide for the closed-form of $F(x)$.

For the generating functions of $F_{2n}$ and $F_{2n+1}$, you could perhaps use identities like

$$F_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^nF_{2k-1} \qquad F_{2n+1}=1+\sum_{k=1}^nF_{2k}.$$

However, in my opinion, for all three GFs it would be easier to just use Binet's formula

$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\bar{\varphi}^n}{\varphi~-~\bar{\varphi}\,},\qquad \varphi,\bar{\varphi}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

One way of proving Binet's formula is with linear algebra, but another way is proving it using the very generating function we just looked at (and using partial fraction decomposition), and in the latter case it is not applicable to the original GF but afterwards can still be used for the other two.

Comment: @vercammen another possible way to use the same technique for the generating function of $F_{2n}$ is to observe that $F_{2n+4}=3F_{2n+2}-F_{2n}$ and similarly for $F_{2n+1}$.

Comment: I still don't get this. I tried using the formula above and got nothing. Also I was thinking about $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f_n x^n  \Rightarrow  f(x)+f(-x) = 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} f_{2n}x^n $ and $f(x)-f(-x) = 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} f_{2n+1}x^n$ Still nothing.

Comment: @vercammen But $f_n+(-1)^nf_n=2f_{2n}$ and $f_n-(-1)^nf_n=2f_{2n+1}$ are *false*, so your implications do not follow. Did you try $$\begin{array}{cl}\sum_{n\ge0}f_{2n}x^n & =\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\varphi^{2n}-\bar{\varphi}^{2n}}{\varphi-\bar{\varphi}}x^n \\ & =\frac{\displaystyle\left[\sum_{n\ge0}(\varphi^2x)^n\right]-\left[\sum_{n\ge0}( \bar{\varphi}^2 x)^n\right]}{\varphi-\bar{\varphi}} \\ & =\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-\varphi^2x}-\frac{1}{1-\bar{\varphi}^2x}}{\varphi-\bar{\varphi}} \\ & = \frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}\end{array}$$ like I suggested?

Comment: oh sorry I claimed that $f(x)+f(-x) = 2\sum_{n \ge 0} f_{2n} x^{2n}$. Isn't it correct?

I did not try you method yet, though it's pretty straightforward. However I am looking for something simpler, like getting the result from just knowing that $f_n = f_{n-1}+ f_{n-2}$.

Comment: @vercammen No, that's not correct. This is correct: $$f(x)+f(-x)=\left[\sum_{n\ge0}f_nx^n\right]+\left[\sum_{n\ge0}f_n(-x)^n\right]=\sum_{n\ge0}\left[f_n+(-1)^nf_n\right]x^n.$$ I am not sure why you prefaced your comment with "I don't get this. I tried using the formula and got nothing," when this formula you have doesn't have anything to do with what anybody has written here. (It is not clear to me how you came to the formula at all.)

Comment: At any rate, I feel the more straightforward way is the simpler way. But if you want to use recursion, as in the beginning of my answer for $\sum f_nx^n$, you will need to have handy a recursion formula for $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2n+1}$ (such is given in Vincent's comment above).

Comment: Ok, I will use you method, but I still do not understand why that formula is wrong. When $n$ is even we sum up all the pair index couples. Like $f(x)+f(-x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f_n(x^n+(-x)^n) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f_n(2x^n)$. When $n$ is odd the terms cancel out.

Comment: @vercammen That is a very nice idea actually now that I see what you're getting at. You have $$\begin{array}{cl}\sum_{n\ge0}f_{2n}x^{n}&=\frac{f(\sqrt{x})+f(-\sqrt{x})}{2} \\ & =\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}-x}+\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}-x}\right) \\ & =\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}.\end{array}$$ That is perfectly valid and I think that solution is even better. I apologize for not understanding your idea earlier.